# How to remove all files NOT ending with certain formats?

Tags: linux, shell

So to remove all files ending with `.lnx`, the cmd would be `rm *.lnx`, right?

If I want to remove all files that do NOT end with [.lnx], what command should I use?

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls | grep -v '\.lnx$' | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 23):

You can use [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching):

```
$ rm !(*.lnx)
```

---

```
!(pattern-list)
    Matches anything except one of the given patterns. 
    A pattern-list is a list of one or more patterns separated by a ‘|’.
```

Comment: Good, but note you'll need `extglob` enabled (with `shopt -s extglob`) to use this.

Comment: In Ubuntu: `extglob` is ON default.

Comment: Did I miss where he said he's on Ubuntu?  I don't see it stated or implied anywhere. Regardless, it's not necessarily going to be on for everyone who comes to this thread for an answer, so it's worth noting.

Answer (score 17):

```
find . -depth 1 -type f -not -name '*.lnx' -delete
```

find all files (`-type f`) in the current directory (`-depth 1`) which do not match the filename (`-not -name '*.lnx'`), and delete them (`-delete`)

As always, test this first. Run it without the `-delete` to see all the files that match.

Comment: `-type f` is not required. He didn't say he wanted to exclude directories.